# Haskell/GHC performance of naive sorts using `filter` / list comprehension

Tags: performance, sorting, haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

Compiling with `-O3`, a program using

```
quicksort []       = []
quicksort (x : xs) = quicksort (filter (< x) xs)
                     ++ [x] ++
                     quicksort (filter (>= x) xs)
```

is 1.1x slower than a program using

```
quicksort2 []       = []
quicksort2 (x : xs) = quicksort2 [y | y <- xs, y < x]
                      ++ [x] ++
                      quicksort2 [y | y <- xs, y >= x]
```

is 6x slower than a program using

```
minisort [] = []
minisort xs = let x = minimum xs
              in  x : minisort (delete x xs)
```

These are not the Haskell-native merge`sort`, and not meant to be.

I noticed `minisort` consistently run much faster than both of the `quicksort`s, which seemed understandable, considering complexities of involved operations. What I don't understand is a consistent slight edge `quicksort2` has over `quicksort`. Are list comprehensions generally more efficient than `filter` expressions?

---

Used by me, so far, were [criterion](http://rextester.com/l/haskell_online_compiler), with `nf`, `ghci`'s `:set +s`, and 2 remote performance-displayant online compilers ([ideone](http://ideone.com), [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/haskell_online_compiler)).

criterion benchmark sorting worst-case `[5000, 4999 .. 1] :: [Int]`:

```
benchmarking quicksort
time                 2.283 s     (2.191 s .. 2.450 s)
                     0.999 R²    (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 2.434 s     (2.368 s .. 2.485 s)
std dev              79.23 ms    (0.0 s .. 88.75 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking quicksort2
time                 2.203 s     (1.982 s .. 2.455 s)
                     0.998 R²    (0.994 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 2.327 s     (2.275 s .. 2.359 s)
std dev              49.11 ms    (0.0 s .. 56.47 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking minisort
time                 257.2 ms    (229.7 ms .. 276.4 ms)
                     0.997 R²    (NaN R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 274.4 ms    (264.3 ms .. 280.9 ms)
std dev              9.714 ms    (2.538 ms .. 12.94 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 16% (moderately inflated)
```

`quicksort2` always (varying test cases, orders, and contexts) performs a bit better than `quicksort`. `minisort`, by far, performs better than both of them.

Comment: What version of GHC is this? How are you measuring speed, and on what inputs? I'm pretty surprised, because `filter` is implemented using a `build/foldr` form that should fuse similarly to the list comprehension. If you're trying things in GHCi, they're not optimized. Note also that there is no `-O3`; just `-O2`. That could change eventually, but it's been that way since the beginning.

Comment: There's no way `minisort` ([selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)) would be faster on any non-tiny list, as it's _O_ (_n_ ²) best-case, whereas any decent sort algorithm has _O_ (_n_ · log _n_) average-case complexity. _How_ did you measure this? In particular, what did you do to make sure the results are actually evaluated? I suspect you only WHNF the sorted lists – that's not sufficient.

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but `minisort` is not a correct implementation. Try `minisort [3,5,6,5,2]`.

Comment: I've let them sort standard-type `Int` lists of 5000 to 10000 elements. I got the factors using both GHC 7.8.0 and GHC 8.0.1, multiple measurement methods and separate programs for each implementation. I'm not an expert though. THX duplode, fixed the bug.

Comment: `print`, no WHNF.

Comment: Please post your benchmark code and the procedure you used to run it. Note also that your "quicksort" is not randomized, so it's susceptible to pathological cases, and that it performs two passes over each list (although the latter may not be terrible here).

Comment: I used the classic famous Haskell 'quicksort' two-liner. As said, wasn't trying to rival `sort`. Updated question description with criterion benchmark.

Comment: The descending list you're testing on is just the sort of pathological input dfeuer is referring to. Can you see why? So you're comparing several quadratic time algorithms. The answer as to why some are slower or faster than others here is not going to be particularly interesting

Comment: I read this a bit wrong. There is no potential for list fusion here. If the difference between `quicksort` and `quicksort2` is real (it's barely statistically significant, and I wouldn't be surprised if there were some silly dependence on which benchmark is run first or whatever) then it's probably something fragile in optimization. Selection sort is simpler than quicksort, so I'm not surprised it's faster when quicksort hits its worst case.

Comment: If you want to have fun playing with sorting in Haskell, I suggest you try writing some merge sorts, heap sorts, and genuine randomized quicksorts.

Comment: The `quicksort`-`quicksort2` difference still irks me though. It's consistent changing order, list size and orderedness.

Comment: Well, that is actually a bit strange. _Why is `filter` slower than a list comprehension here_? Perhaps you should have left `minisort` out of this question...